# Combining code for multiple sensors in one program (Arduino)

Tags: programming, sensors

I need to operate 2 different sensors (gas and DHT11) simultaneously. I have managed to run each one of them separately and I don't know how to manipulate the code so they could work together.

Here are the sketches:

Gas sensor MQ2 code :

```
int redLed = 12;
int greenLed = 11;
int buzzer = 10;
int smokeA0 = A5;
// threshold value
int sensorThres = 400;

void setup() {
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(smokeA0, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int analogSensor = analogRead(smokeA0);

  Serial.print("Concentration: ppm ");
  Serial.println(analogSensor);
  // Checks if it has reached the threshold value
  if (analogSensor > sensorThres)
  {
    digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    tone(buzzer, 1000, 200);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
  delay(100);
```

This is the DHT11 code :

```
#include <SimpleDHT.h>

int pinDHT11 = 7;
SimpleDHT11 dht11(pinDHT11);

void setup() {
    // start working...
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  Serial.println("Temperature and Humidity Data");
}

void loop() {

  delay (250);
  // read without samples.
  byte temperature = 0;
  byte humidity = 0;
  int err = SimpleDHTErrSuccess;
  if ((err = dht11.read(&temperature, &humidity, NULL)) != SimpleDHTErrSuccess) {
    Serial.print("Read DHT11 failed, err="); Serial.println(err);delay(1000);
    return;
  }
  Serial.print((int)temperature); Serial.print(" *C, "); 
  Serial.print((int)humidity); Serial.println(" H");

  // DHT11 sampling rate is 1HZ.
  delay(1500);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the 3 major area's of the code, the include/declaration section where files are included and global variables are declared.  Then combine the setup() functions and then combine the loop() functions. Ends up looking something like below. However you may have to tweek the timing of your delays

```
#include <SimpleDHT.h>
int redLed = 12;
int greenLed = 11;
int buzzer = 10;
int smokeA0 = A5;
// threshold value
int sensorThres = 400;
int pinDHT11 = 7;
SimpleDHT11 dht11(pinDHT11);

void setup() {
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(smokeA0, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Starting");
}

void loop() {
  int analogSensor = analogRead(smokeA0);
  Serial.print("Concentration: ppm ");
  Serial.println(analogSensor);
  // Checks if it has reached the threshold value
  if (analogSensor > sensorThres)
  {
    digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    tone(buzzer, 1000, 200);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
  delay(250);
  // read without samples.
  byte temperature = 0;
  byte humidity = 0;
  int err = SimpleDHTErrSuccess;
  if ((err = dht11.read(&temperature, &humidity, NULL)) != SimpleDHTErrSuccess) {
    Serial.print("Read DHT11 failed, err="); Serial.println(err);delay(1000);
    return;
  }
  Serial.print((int)temperature); Serial.print(" *C, "); 
  Serial.print((int)humidity); Serial.println(" H");

  // DHT11 sampling rate is 1HZ.
  delay(1500);
}
```

The other way you can do it, which keeps it easyer to read, is move the contents of each main loop into its own function, and then call the two functions from inside loop().  This allows you to easly comment out one of the functions to trouble shoot somthing, or even allow you to call one more often then the other depending upon your needs, (can look at the blink without delay example for how to manage timing)

```
#include <SimpleDHT.h>
int redLed = 12;
int greenLed = 11;
int buzzer = 10;
int smokeA0 = A5;
// threshold value
int sensorThres = 400;
int pinDHT11 = 7;
SimpleDHT11 dht11(pinDHT11);

    void setup() {
      pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(smokeA0, INPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("Starting");
    }


void loop1(){
   int analogSensor = analogRead(smokeA0);

  Serial.print("Concentration: ppm ");
  Serial.println(analogSensor);
  // Checks if it has reached the threshold value
  if (analogSensor > sensorThres)
  {
    digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    tone(buzzer, 1000, 200);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
  delay(100);
}


void loop2(){
  delay (250);
  // read without samples.
  byte temperature = 0;
  byte humidity = 0;
  int err = SimpleDHTErrSuccess;
  if ((err = dht11.read(&temperature, &humidity, NULL)) != SimpleDHTErrSuccess) {
    Serial.print("Read DHT11 failed, err="); Serial.println(err);delay(1000);
    return;
  }
  Serial.print((int)temperature); Serial.print(" *C, "); 
  Serial.print((int)humidity); Serial.println(" H");

  // DHT11 sampling rate is 1HZ.
  delay(1500);
}


void loop() {
  loop1();
  loop2();
}
```